# Openstack with neutron on two physical nodes

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

We have two physical system(ubuntu14.04.2) having 2 physical NIC each.
Is it possible to install openstack(juno) with neutron on same ?

Official documentation says that we need 3 nodes with network node having 3 NICs

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: Sounds like you've answered your own question! Also, this is not a programming question and better belongs on a group like Super User or Server Fault.

Comment: thanks for comment Barett. Just wanted to confirm from experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install all of OpenStack on a single system for development and testing purposes.  Given that a single node installation is possible, it should follow that a two-node installation is also possible (and it is).

The documentation recommends three NICs because this leads to the simplest configuration.  However, you can run a network host with two NICs.  There are several different traffic types you'll be dealing with:

- Public web (Horizon) traffic
- Public API traffic (if you expose the APIs)
- Internal API traffic
- Tenant internal network traffic (traffic between Nova instances and the compute host)
- Tenant external network traffic (traffic between Nova instances and "the rest of the world")
- Storage (transferring Glance images, iSCSI for Cinder volumes, etc)

Being able to segment these in a meaningful fashion can lead to a more manageable and more performant environment.  With only two NICs, you are probably looking at one for "internal traffic" (interal api, storage, tenant internal networking, etc) and one for "external traffic" (dashboard, public apis, tenant external traffic).  This is certainly possible, but it means, for example, that excessive traffic from your tenants can impact access to the dashboard, and that a high volume of storage traffic can impact access to Nova instances.

If/when your environment grows beyond two nodes, you may want to investigate adding additional NICs to your configuration.